# How to configure EC2 to process emoji in my spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, locale, telegram-bot

I'm currently trying to run a Telegram bot on **EC2 instance**.

But the problem is - all non-english symbol are replaced.
On the screenshot you can see how emojis are replaces (e.g. before 'Settings' word)
Or how russian word is totally messed.

[image: Telegram screenshot]

What I have tried so far:

1. Run java with arguments:

> ```
> java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -jar
> ```

2. Set locale in application.properties

> ```
> spring.mandatory-file-encoding=UTF-8
>
> spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
>
> spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
> ```

3. Set /etc/environment locale

> ```
> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk"
> LANG=en_US.utf-8
> LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
> ```

**Please note:** My messages / button text values are stored in appropriate locale bundles in app resources. And considering that bot still works (he recognizes the value of message he receives even if its messed) I assume that it has something to do with java app.

**P.S. When I run it locally - it works perfectly.**

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: So what does the ec2 instance output if you type `locale` on the terminal?

Comment: @Kayaman everything is UTF8:   
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8

Comment: ..and the locale settings are the same on your computer? You've got [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), and now you have the ungrateful task of finding out why.

Comment: @Kayaman but the problem is also with simple russian words, so it's not only emojis being messed up :(

Comment: I never said it's only related to emojis.

Answer (score 1):

After tons of answers and attempts, here's my solution:

As my text values are stored in .properties bundles, `Standard Java API is designed to use ISO 8859-1 encoding for properties files.`

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/properties-files.html#

So before doing 'mvn clean package', I manually decoded my properties files with

> native2ascii -encoding UTF-8
>   src/main/resources/messages_en.properties
>   src/main/resources/messages_en.properties

Hope it helps.

If anyone has better solution - please let me know.